How to intercept the taskbar buttons calls?
I'm trying to intercept calls to the taskbar buttons, for this I'm hooking the CoCreateInstance function to detect when it creates the ItaskbarList4 .
I would like to find another way to hook these functions as this way I need to start the explorer suspended
CoCreateInstance_H is getting called and I'm creating a subclass from the ItaskbarList4 pointer, at MyTaskbarList, HrInit() it's returning S_OK
however, the other functions on MyTaskbarList aren't getting called, like AddTab, RemoveTab, RegisterTab, the taskbar ain't crashing and "looks" to continue working properly.
I'm trying to figure out what's wrong.
inline HRESULT(WINAPI* CoCreateInstance_O)(REFCLSID rclsid, LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter, DWORD dwClsContext, REFIID riid, LPVOID* ppv) = CoCreateInstance;

class MyTaskbarList : public ITaskbarList4 {
public:

    MyTaskbarList(ITaskbarList4* original) : m_original(original) {}

    // IUnknown methods

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) override {

        if (riid == __uuidof(IUnknown) || riid == __uuidof(ITaskbarList4)) {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<ITaskbarList4*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }

        *ppvObject = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() override {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_refCount);
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() override {
        ULONG refCount = InterlockedDecrement(&m_refCount);
        if (refCount == 0) {
            delete this;
        }
        return refCount;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE HrInit() override {
        HRESULT hr = m_original->HrInit();
        return hr;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddTab(HWND hwnd) override {
        return m_original->AddTab(hwnd);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DeleteTab(HWND hwnd) override {
        return m_original->DeleteTab(hwnd);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ActivateTab(HWND hwnd) override {
        return m_original->ActivateTab(hwnd);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetActiveAlt(HWND hwnd) override {
        return m_original->SetActiveAlt(hwnd);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE MarkFullscreenWindow(HWND hwnd, BOOL fFullscreen) override {
        return m_original->MarkFullscreenWindow(hwnd, fFullscreen);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetProgressValue(HWND hwnd, ULONGLONG ullCompleted, ULONGLONG ullTotal) override {
        return m_original->SetProgressValue(hwnd, ullCompleted, ullTotal);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetProgressState(HWND hwnd, TBPFLAG tbpFlags) override {
        return m_original->SetProgressState(hwnd, tbpFlags);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RegisterTab(HWND hwndTab, HWND hwndMDI) override {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"RegisterTab");
        return m_original->RegisterTab(hwndTab, hwndMDI);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE UnregisterTab(HWND hwndTab) override {
        return m_original->UnregisterTab(hwndTab);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetTabOrder(HWND hwndTab, HWND hwndInsertBefore) override {
        return m_original->SetTabOrder(hwndTab, hwndInsertBefore);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetTabActive(HWND hwndTab, HWND hwndMDI, DWORD dwReserved) override {
        return m_original->SetTabActive(hwndTab, hwndMDI, dwReserved);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ThumbBarAddButtons(HWND hwnd, UINT cButtons, LPTHUMBBUTTON pButton) override {
        return m_original->ThumbBarAddButtons(hwnd, cButtons, pButton);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ThumbBarUpdateButtons(HWND hwnd, UINT cButtons, LPTHUMBBUTTON pButton) override {
        return m_original->ThumbBarUpdateButtons(hwnd, cButtons, pButton);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ThumbBarSetImageList(HWND hwnd, HIMAGELIST himl) override {
        return m_original->ThumbBarSetImageList(hwnd, himl);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetOverlayIcon(HWND hwnd, HICON hIcon, LPCWSTR pszDescription) override {
        return m_original->SetOverlayIcon(hwnd, hIcon, pszDescription);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetThumbnailTooltip(HWND hwnd, LPCWSTR pszTip) override {
        return m_original->SetThumbnailTooltip(hwnd, pszTip);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetThumbnailClip(HWND hwnd, RECT* prcClip) override {
        return m_original->SetThumbnailClip(hwnd, prcClip);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetTabProperties(HWND hwndTab, STPFLAG stpFlags) override {
        return m_original->SetTabProperties(hwndTab, stpFlags);
    }

private:
    ITaskbarList4* m_original;
    LONG m_refCount;
};



MyTaskbarList* myTaskbarList = nullptr;
HRESULT WINAPI CoCreateInstance_H(REFCLSID rclsid, LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter, DWORD dwClsContext, REFIID riid, LPVOID* ppv)
{
    if (rclsid == CLSID_TaskbarList)
    {
        if (riid == IID_ITaskbarList4)
        {
            ITaskbarList4* original;
            HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance_O(rclsid, pUnkOuter, dwClsContext, riid, (void**)&original);
            OutputDebugStringW(L"CoCreateInstance_H");

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                myTaskbarList = new MyTaskbarList(original);
                *ppv = myTaskbarList;
                OutputDebugStringW(L"success");
            }
            return hr;
        }
        else
            OutputDebugStringW(L"!IID");
    }
    return CoCreateInstance_O(rclsid, pUnkOuter, dwClsContext, riid, ppv);
}

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Detours.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)CoCreateInstance_O, CoCreateInstance_H);
            DetourTransactionCommit();
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}


Your QueryInterface() implementation is in violation of a core COM rule: "It Must Be Possible to Query Successfully for Any Interface on an Object from Any Other Interface".

@IInspectable the QueryInterface() isn't even getting called, I added a breakpoint to all these override functions, and the unique that gets called is HrInit()

It isn't being called because your CoCreateInstance_H() implementation is too restrictive. Your (non-conforming) MyTaskbarList is only ever created if a client asks for an IID_ITaskbarList4 interface. I would assume that the Shell requests the IID_ITaskbarList interface initially and only navigates to inherited interfaces when it needs to. But at that point, your code is out of the loop.

@IInspectable looks like it is storing the ITaskbarList4, as it only calls it once, "MyTaskbarList  is only ever created if a client asks for an IID_ITaskbarList4 interface." for the other interfaces, the hook calls the original function CoCreateInstance_O, wdym with the code is out of the loop? MyTaskbarList is a global variable.

CoCreateInstance_H() delegates to CoCreateInstance_O() for all requests that do not match CLSID_TaskbarList/IID_ITaskbarList4. When the Shell requests an IID_ITaskbarList interface it gets the original COM object from your CoCreateInstance_H() implementation. That object is unaware of your MyTaskbarList. You've missed your only chance of sneaking in.

@IInspectable i had verified it before, CoCreateInstance_H is called with CLSID_TaskbarList only once, I had an else in that if to print if it queried for a different IID, I don't know why I removed it, I'll add it to the question

"CoCreateInstance_H is called with CLSID_TaskbarList only once" - Yes, of course. It is COM's standard class factory. Once it has returned an object through the requested interface pointer its job is over. After that point everything is handled by the COM object, including reference counting, resource cleanup, and interface hierarchy navigation. To make that work you are well advised to follow COM's rules meticulously, especially when infiltrating a foreign interface hierarchy.
